# Function to match Html Element against a given object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to javascript and newer to es6, so the worst possible combination, but please don't give up!

I want to build a function that compares an html element with an object and returns a callback.

The object will be something like:

```
const Models = {
    button1: {
        nodeName: 'BUTTON',
        className: /save/.test(element.className),
        action: 'save'
    },
    input1: {
        nodeName: 'INPUT',
        dataset: {validate: true},
        action: 'validate'
    },
    select1: {
        nodeName: 'SELECT',
        type: 'SELECT-ONE',
        action: 'whatever'
    }
}

Models.getAction = function(element) {
    for (let model in Models) {
        // do the magic seomething like:
        if (model.nodeName === element.nodeName /* && condition 2 for the variable second property*/) {
            return model.action;
        }
    }
}
```

The example is random, the important part is that the model will have for the first two properties a valid html element property name and their values can be either string, array, or function. I'm not sure about the structure of the object, any correction is welcome. So, in fact, it is necessary to somehow validate the first two properties of the model. The question is what the second condition is gona be, or if there are different ways to achieve the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @cloned My question is the function, as you can see is not a proper function, is just an idea about what I want to obtain.

Comment: @cloned I edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: `classname` of first object will be a boolean. Does not seem useful. Then: "first two properties": if order is significant (and apparently it is), then you need an array, not a plain object.

Comment: Should an element match even when it does not have a model-property at all?

Comment: What if `element.dataset` has a matching `validate` property, but also another property, should it be rejected as a match with `input1` because of that?

Comment: @trincot Probably you missed the part where I said that `The example is random,`. For the first two conditions I will hardcode the filters depending on needs, the purpose is to retreive the action associated with corresponding pattern. There will be elements matching multiple patterns, and yes, order will have a role, but I will prioritize the patterns according my needs. I also noticed that the result will be valid when there is no matching pattern, that is an error. For the rest I will post another comment.

Comment: I did not miss that the example is random, there is no problem with that. I have elaborated on my previous remarks in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- It is common practice to reserve names with an initial capital for constructors/classes. For other purposes, start variables names with lower case.
- You should not do `className: /save/.test(element.className)` when `element` is not within scope -- this will execute right there on the spot. Instead make it a function.
- *"the first two properties"*: objects are not really suitable for giving properties some order, so that one should be considered first. From your own answer it seems you actually mean *"ignore the `action` property"*.
- For the same reason, comparing objects with `JSON.stringify` may give unexpected results, since the order of the properties could be different than expected.
- The `type` property of a `select` DOM element can be "select-one", but not in all-capitals.
- There does not seem any role for the property names of the model object. You could just make it an array.
- In your solution, an element will not be rejected when it lacks some property that is present in the model.
- In your solution, an element with more dataset properties than in the model will always be rejected as a match.
- a `dataset` property cannot be anything else than a string, so there will not be a match with `dataset: {validate: true}`
- `/save/.test` will also match with `saved` and `resave`

Here is a snippet with 3 calls that return an action, and 3 that don't:

```js
const models = [{
    nodeName: 'BUTTON',
    className: (className) => /(^|\s)save($|\s)/.test(className),
    action: 'save'
}, {
    nodeName: 'INPUT',
    dataset: {validate: "true"},
    action: 'validate'
}, {
    nodeName: 'SELECT',
    type: 'select-one',
    action: 'whatever'
}];

const getAction = function(element) {
    let match = models.find(model => Object.entries(model).every(([key, value]) => {
        // avoid action key
        if (key === 'action') return true;
        let elemVal = element[key];
        // check if properties exists in both
        return elemVal !== undefined && (
            typeof value === 'function' ? value(elemVal)
            : Object(value) === value ? Object(elemVal) === elemVal && 
                 Object.entries(value).every(([prop, propVal]) => elemVal[prop] === propVal) 
            : value === elemVal
        );
    }));
    return match && match.action;
};

console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("sel1")));
console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("inp1")));
console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("btn1")));
console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("btn2")));
console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("sel2")));
console.log(getAction(document.getElementById("inp2")));
```

```html
<select id="sel1">
    <option>choice 1</option>
    <option>choice 2</option>
</select>
<input id="inp1" data-validate="true" data-required="false">
<input id="inp2" data-required="false">
<button id="btn1" class="bold save">Something</button>
<button id="btn2" class="saved">No match</button>
<select id="sel2" multiple>
    <option>choice 1</option>
    <option>choice 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice work. It seems to do exactly what I need, not sure about the case when action will be a function. I will do some tests to see if there are any unforeseen situations, and I will probably accept your solution.

Comment: Thanks. As for the array instead of the object, I looked for some meaningful names to distinguish the patterns, but this is not relevant, I can use comments.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it:

```
const getAction = function(element) {
    let valid;
    for (let model in Models) {
        valid = true;
        // iterate model properties
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Models[model])) {
            // avoid action key
            if (key !== 'action') {
                // check if properties exists in both
                if (element[key]) {
                    switch (typeof value) {
                        case 'function':
                            valid = valid && Models[model][key](element);
                            break;
                        case 'object':
                            valid = valid && JSON.stringify(Models[model][key]) === JSON.stringify(element[key]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            valid = valid && Models[model][key] === element[key];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (valid) {
            return Models[model].action;
        }
    }
};
```

If no one provides a better solution I will accept this solution.